# Why is autocorrelation used without normalization in signal processing field?

Tags: correlation, statistics

According to the wikipedia([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)), autocorrelation has two definition.

In statistics, the definition of the autocorrelation between times $s$ and $t$ is like the following:
$$\displaystyle R(s,t) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X_t-\mu_t)(X_s-\mu_s]}{\sigma_t\sigma_s}$$

---

However, in signal processing, the above definition is **often** used without the normalizaiton.

According to digital communication written by Bernard Sklar,
$$R_x(\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)x(t+\tau)du$$

$$R_X(\tau)=\mathbb{E}\{X(t)X(t+\tau)\}$$

Where \begin{array}{a}
\tau & \mbox{ is the difference between } t \mbox{ and }s.\\
x(t) & \mbox{ is real-valued energy signal.}\\
X(t) & \mbox{ is a random process. }\end{array}

Comment: sometimes all we care about are relative values of the autocorrelation.  normalizing it simply means that it's relative to $R_x(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Autocorrelation (sometimes also termed aucovariance) is often used in the context of stationnary time signals.  As the $\sigma_t$ and $\sigma_s$ are "equal". Since the autocorrelation is symmetric and peaks at $\tau=0$, $R_x(\tau)$ (as noted by @robert bristow-johnson) is often regarded as the natural reference. In a lot of applications, one mostly look at its scale-variant properties: as a measure on how signal chunks look similar, or modeling its decay, or by fitting a linear model through it.

Sometimes, to distinguish the normalized version, it is called an [autocorrelation coefficient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance#Normalization).

When dealing with non-stationnary signals, it would be unnatural to stationnarize it artificially. For instance, the [Wigner-Ville distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function) is based on the Fourier transform of the unnormalized non-stationary autocorrelation function.

Answer (score 0):

Usually such operation are made as "filtering" technique to improve signal to noise ratio. a threshold than is set to derive probability of detection given a certain false alarm rate. These two probabilities are not impacted by the scaling of the two signals - thus the normalization is nor required and the processing associated with it is saved.